# Sharepoint 2010 custom fields xml <PropertySchema>

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, custom-field-types, xml

lately I have been trying to develop a custom field (cascading dropdown) for sharepoint 2010.  I am using the sample from codeplex.  the problem is that the sample is for sharepoint 2007 and uses the  as follows in XML.

```
 <PropertySchema>
  <Fields>
    <Field Name="SiteUrl" Hidden="TRUE" DisplayName="SiteUrl" MaxLength="500" DisplaySize="100" Type="Text">
    </Field>
```

for some reason in Sharepoint 2010 this seems not to be working and is giving the following error:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'ASP._controltemplates_cascadingdropdowneditfieldcontrol_ascx' to type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.IFieldEditor'.
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.FieldCustomizationPage.CreateChildControls()
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.FieldNewPage.CreateChildControls()
>    at System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls()
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.FieldCustomizationPage.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.FieldNewPage.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
>    at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
>    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

is there a way to add same things in CreateChildControl instead of PropertySchema?? or anyone has suggestions to solve this issue?

Comment: Could you link to the example on CodePlex, please?

Comment: hi, the following is the link to what seems like the project, I managed to find same one open source but did not keep the link :S. basically it is the same as this one http://cascddlistwithfilter.codeplex.com/

Comment: I can post the xml file if it is of any help, and the class using ifieldeditor main parts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this site which did the cascading drop down very easily: please refer to 
http://www.sharepointkings.com/2010/09/sharepoint-cascading-drop-downs-using.html

Answer (score 1):

This error may occure if your custom editor control     'ASP._controltemplates_cascadingdropdowneditfieldcontrol_ascx does not implement     IFieldEditor interface or doing it wrong. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb802857.aspx) recommends to use custom editor controls. [Here](http://www.infoq.com/articles/Dressel-Gogolowicz-wss-security) is another greate example to start with. Hope it helps!

Comment: Bassist's answer is the correct one BTW. The lack of implementing the IFieldEditor interface is what would cause this error. The "Answer" to DL a new sample doesn't address the actual error and is not the solution to the problem.